# Difference between frequency domain in mp3 and wav?

Tags: matlab, audio, mp3, wav, frequency

I have plotted the frequency domain for an mp3 file and wav file as shown in Figure below.
They are in dotted blue and dark orange respectively. 
Why is there no difference which I thought the frequency of mp3 should be lower.

[image: Frequency domain for mp3 and wav file]

Comment: Wave files have a higher frequency range (I think it was upto 18kHz), however the file has a cut off at 15kHz, which is the reason the dont differ. The question is how both files were generated?

Comment: I downloaded the mp3 file from the website and I decode the mp3 file into wav file. The wav file is larger but I wonder why the frequency domain shown no difference.

Comment: So you converted a file with a low frequency content to a format which can hold a bigger frequency content expecting that it will have more information ? How should that work? Where should the more information come from? Try it the other way, find a "original" wav file and convert it to mp3 and compare those ...

Comment: If so, what is the purpose of mp3 decoder since it could not rebuild and provide the original wav quality?

Comment: A file converter has only the purpose to change the file format. In the case that the specifications of one format are lower than of the original format a conversion results in a loss of information. In the opposite case the information wont change. Or would you be surprise when pouring 300ml Water from a glass into a bottle, which has a volume of 1000ml, that there is only 300ml in the bottle?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, I actually tried to decode a 3MB mp3 file to a 20MB wav file. I wonder why the size become larger and what causes the large file size of wav file?

Comment: The question regarding difference of file format are very easy to find with google, once you read about wav and mp3 in general you will understand it directly. Take your time with that ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to https://dsp.stackexchange.com